# Change android:icon dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How to change the the **action bar icon** dynamically in the JAVA code?

*See the image, the icon number 2.*

[image]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar@2x.png))</sub>

What I want to do is a flip between two icons I got. For example when the user click on the "search icon[2]" it will be change to the world icon.

So there's the code I got.

menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/actionMenu"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Then we inizializate the menu at JAVA code with this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Then, here we go to handle this.
First, we make a switch to know if it exist an click or not.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionMenu:
            changeIcon(); // Here we call that magic function
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

So, then we call the changeIcon(); this function needs the magic

```
private void changeIcon(){
        try {
            if(this.theSwitcher){
                // What code need this function?
                // I just need to change icon1 to icon2
                this.theSwitcher = false;
            } else {
                // What code need this function?
                // I just need to change icon2 to icon1
                this.quince = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyBad", "Error: " + e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
private void changeIcon(){
        MenuItem mi = mMenu.findItem(R.id.actionMenu);

        try {
            if(this.theSwitcher){
                // What code need this function?
                // I just need to change icon1 to icon2
                mi.setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
                this.theSwitcher = false;
            } else {
                // What code need this function?
                // I just need to change icon2 to icon1
                mi.setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
                this.quince = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyBad", "Error: " + e);
        }

    }
```

And in

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    mMenu = menu;
}
```

Comment: But that code is for change the icon app. I want to change the action icon... As the example in the image, is the search icon. But thank you.